# Can i call a function in sql server from asp.net mvc?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I have the following statement in sql server:

```
EXEC StoredProcedureName "email", "pinNumber";
```

and I have the following method in ASP.NET MVC written in C#:

```
name:encryptPinNumber
input parameter (email,pinNumber)
return type: string
return variable: encryptedPinNumber
```

Can I call `encryptPinNumber`in SQL Server and give it email, pinNumber and then store `encryptedPinNumber` in my EXEC statement like such?

```
EXEC StoredProcedureName "email", "encryptedPinNumber";
```

Comment: Yes, you can. Are you asking how?

Comment: yes, id like to know how  :)

Comment: That's pretty broad. Have you tried anything yet? If nothing else, there are plenty of existing questions about using ADO.NET to call a stored procedure.

Comment: Use ADO.NET: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310070

Comment: Thanks @ Tieson T. and @Brain Mains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple if not the most elegant/efficient way is below:

```
private string encryptPinNumber(string email, string pinNumber)
{

    string connectionString = "Data Source=DBServerName;Initial Catalog=DBName;Integrated Security=true;";
    var con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
    var cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("StoredProcedureName", con);
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@email", email));
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@pinNumber", pinNumber));
    con.Open();

    string encryptedpinNumber = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    con.Close();

    return encryptedpinNumber;

}
```

But please refer to the links already posted by others.

Comment: SqlConnection and SqlCommand both implement IDisposable, so you could wrap either one in a using block. Then you don't need to manually close the connection.